# How to format a csv file to put all information on a line and then move down?

Tags: python, csv

I have a file that takes information and writes it to a csv file.  I am having trouble getting it to format the way I want.  It is looping 10 times and the information is there I can confirm.  I am including the code to show you the exact setup of the csv writing part.

Here is my code:

```
outfile = open('Accounts_Details.csv', 'a')
for i in range(0, 11):
    #Calling all the above functions
    soc_auth_requests()
    create_account()
    config_admin_create()
    account_user_create()
    account_activate()
    account_config_DNS_create()

    #Creating the dictionary for the CSV file with the data fields made and modified from before
    #It is necessary this be done after the above method calls to ensure the data field values are correct
    data = {
        'Account_Name': acc_name,
        'Account_Id': acc_id,
        'User_Email': user_email,
        'User_id': user_id
     }

    #Creating a csv file and writing the dictionary titled "data" to it

    for key, value in sorted(data.items()):
        outfile.write('\t' + str(value))

outfile.write('\n')
```

So I have four bits of data in the dict and I want the format to be laid out in the csv file so that the four bits of info are put on one line and when it loops through the for loop it moves to the next line and does the same there.

Ex.

```
name1, id1, email1, uId1
name2, id2, email2, uId2
name3, id3, email3, uId3
```

I assume it has to do with how I open the file, but I am not sure and can't figure it out.

Thanks for the help!

Here is the current output I am getting.  I want all the 1's to be on one line and then move down.

```
name1
id1
email1
uID1
name2
id2
email2
uID2
```

Comment: What is the current output that you are getting when you execute your code?

Comment: I updated it with what I currently have

Comment: I see here you are using the tab character `\t` - you sure you want to be using this rather than `,`?

Comment: I don't have a problem with how they are separated on one line, what I care about is that everything associated with account 1 is on one line and then account 2 is on the second line.

Comment: Can be closed now I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your file opening arguments are the issue -- I wasn't able to replicate the issue. However, you could probably streamline the code and remove any possibility of an issue by using list comprehensions for your data:

```
for i in range(12):
    data = {
        'Account_Name': 'AccountName',
    'Account_Id': '#12345',
    'User_Email': 'a@b',
    'User_id': 'LOGGER'
    }

    with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(', '.join(data.values())))
```

Comment: The formatting here was weird. It should be reformatted. (I'm not used to pasting in code snippets). It ran otherwise in Python 2.7 without any imports.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting arguments from last statement:

```
    for key, value in sorted(data.items()):
        outfile.write('\t' + str(value))

# outfile.write('\n')
# modified for
outfile.close()
```

please let me know how it was and if this worked!
:)

Comment: Ok so it doesn't look like the file is changing at all?  Do I need to delete the csv file everytime I run it?  I am trying that now.

Comment: Now I am getting an error:  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: no, is not necessary because you are using  "open('Accounts_Details.csv', 'a')" append argument.
Please edit your question with all working code (including your funcs)

Comment: It was,  stuff I didn't want was being saved in there and the 'a' was making it start where it left off so it was necessary.  Thanks for the help.  I made some modifications and got.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the csv module which will automagically format the line for you:

```
outfile = open('Accounts_Details.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, [ 'Account_Name', 'Account_Id', 'User_Email', 'User_id' ])
# optionaly if you want a header line:
writer.writeheader()

for i in range(0, 11):
    ...
    data = {
        'Account_Name': acc_name,
        'Account_Id': acc_id,
        'User_Email': user_email,
        'User_id': user_id
     }
     writer.writerow(data)

outfile.close()
```